# So which SE site would be good to ask about ways to use ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to write a proposal by ChatGPT with at least 10 cited references in A4 paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75979481/how-to-write-a-proposal-by-chatgpt-with-at-least-10-cited-references-in-a4-paper)

But it has been deleted and banned as you can see below and [this link](https://rentry.co/c97zq):

[image]

Comment: Did you ask ChatGPT which StackExchange site would be an acceptable place for this question? I'm honestly curious.

Comment: *"ChatGPT is at capacity right now"* (2023-04-10T183200Z+0). Homework due tomorrow morning? (Sorry for the time zoneism.)

Comment: Users are not question banned after a single poorly received question.  Your question was out of scope at Stack Overflow, thus it was deleted, since there was no way to modify the question to be within scope.

Comment: "Write a proposal" would depend on what *kind* of proposal, and even then, tips for asking ChatGPT is probably off-topic for most of the SE sites.

Comment: ChatGPT's response is not surprising (*[Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour)*), but there is not much on [*Artificial Intelligence*'s meta site](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/). One is *[Are questions about specific web applications, i.e. ChatGPT, on-topic on Artificial Intelligence?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2909/are-questions-about-specific-web-apps-i-e-chatgpt-on-topic-on-ai)*. E.g. *"debugging and technical support questions are off-topic."* and *""how does this work" questions are generally on-topic; "how do I use this" are typically not."*

Comment: Note: ChatGPT [will ***fake***](https://simonwillison.net/2023/Mar/10/chatgpt-internet-access/) (that is, lie about) using provided URLs for context. In other words, it is living in the 2021 world.

Comment: Meh. That's ChatGPT news.

Comment: *"So which SE site "* - why *must* it be posted on an SE site? The rest of the web exists, use it. If only to better understand the value in avoiding questions that'll trigger a whole lot of debate and guesswork.

Comment: The first level of defence is the ***spell checker*** in your browser (or the equivalent). ***Use it.*** For instance, [the GitHub page](https://github.com/Startup-Data/SatLunNeh/tree/master/documents/Proposals/ChatGPT) and [other places](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86885/is-the-nazi-party-legal-in-the-german-parliament) are riddled with errors. The second level could be ChatGPT as it is really good at spelling and grammar (but ***always*** be sceptical of its output, as ChatGPT is a ***pathological liar***. For instance, does the result actually make sense?).

Comment: For instance, you can prompt it with *"Correct spelling and grammar in "<A whole sentence or paragraph>"*. [Example](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/31835/can-patients-in-the-uk-be-seen-at-home-by-telemedicinie): `Correct spelling and grammar for "I like to know the answer of above question for patients"`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There simply isn't a site in the Stack Exchange network to ask questions about how to use ChatGPT as a consumer.

Answer (score 1):

The most relevant one about skills for using ChatGPT and other generative AI tools as a user is the [beta GenAI](https://genai.stackexchange.com) site. I was once very confused why we need a GenAI SE when there is already [artificial intelligence SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com), until I realize the scope of the beta site is about using GenAI tools instead of the algorithms behind the AI and LLM tools. However, as your question is currently worded, I think it will also be closed on GenAI SE.